# How to initialise multiple database engines for while starting a python-flask application?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a python-flask application where I initialise database engines at the time starting the server. This is how my app.py file looks like.

```
import statements
from dbmanager import datasource

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.secret_key = 'bob'
api = Api(app)
HERE = Path(__file__).parent

for api_class_file in HERE.glob("apis/*.py"):
    api_class_name = api_class_file.stem
    api_module = import_module(f"apis.{api_class_name}")
    api_class = getattr(api_module, api_class_name)
    if api_class_name != '__init__':
        api.add_resource(api_class, f"/{api_class_name}".lower())

app.ls_sf_db_env = 'prod'
app.ls_config = config_reader.get_config('prod')

# Initialise the connection pool
datasource.initialize_all_site_engines(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I prepared the datasource file to and used SQLAlchemy to create & initialise multiple engines for different connections as below:

```
from flask import current_app
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

site_name = {"AP":"DBAP10", "GL":"DBGL10"}

def lookup(site):
    return current_app.ls_db_connection_pool[site]

def initialize_all_site_engines(app):
    conf, sf_db_env = app.ls_config, app.ls_sf_db_env
    ls_db_connection_pool = {}

    if sf_db_env == 'test':
        engine = create_connection_pool('AP')
        ls_db_connection_pool['AP'] = engine
        ls_db_connection_pool['GL'] = engine
    else:
        ls_db_connection_pool['AP'] = create_connection_pool('AP')
        ls_db_connection_pool['GL'] = create_connection_pool('GL')
    app.ls_db_connection_pool = ls_db_connection_pool

def create_connection_pool(site):
    print(f'Creating Engine for: {site}')
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    host = 'host'
    dbname = site_name[site]
    url = f"mssql+pymssql://{username}:{password}@{host}/{dbname}"
    engine = create_engine(url, encoding='utf-8', max_overflow=3, pool_size=5, pool_recycle=3600)
    return engine
```

If the value of `sf_db_env` is not `test` I am initialising multiple production engines for the respective databases. In our project, we have multiple sites with multiple databases as below:
For example: `AP` is a site with database: `DBAP10`. `FS` is a site with database: `DBFS10`
When I start the server as `python app.py` I see this log on my terminal:

```
Creating Engine for: DBAP10
engine created for AP
Creating Engine for: DBGL10
engine created for GL
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
2020-12-03 14:38:18,392 - _internal - INFO -  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

And in my API class, I am using

```
engine = datasource.lookup('AP')
connection = engine.connect()
do_something_with_connection
```

I cannot test my code for multiple sites/databases as we only have the database set up for the site 'AP' at the moment. But the multiple site environment is going to come in 2021 & we're told to configure connection parameters as such right now

Could anyone let me know if the way I am creating multiple engines while the server starts is the right way to do ? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i can't really tell you if the way you are doing this is the correct one, but i recommend using docker/docker-compose to create some database/site dummies and test it yourself.

Comment: I am trying to connect to multiple database or create multiple connection objects while the app.py launches.

Comment: Create multiple database containers before launching app.py and test your way of connecting with these containers, by reading data from each.